# Implementing RoutePreviewNavigationTemplate

Tags: android-auto

Hi im Trying to implement a Route Preview with a Dummy Coordinate but I get this Error

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pkg.ir, PID: 23089
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: All rows must have either a distance or duration span attached to either its title or texts

This is My code

And im using this library: implementation "androidx.car.app:app:1.4.0-rc02"

```
class RoutePreviewScreen(carContext: CarContext) : Screen(carContext) {

@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {
    val builder = RoutePreviewNavigationTemplate.Builder()
        .setTitle("Route Details")
        .setHeaderAction(Action.APP_ICON)

    val currentLocation = CarLocation.create(19.269160, -103.754996)

    val locationA = CarLocation.create(19.2689369, -103.7636865)
    val markerA = PlaceMarker.Builder().setColor(CarColor.RED).build()
    val placeA = Place.Builder(locationA).setMarker(markerA).build()

    val distancia = 5
    val duracion = 20

    val distanceSpan = DistanceSpan.create(Distance.create(distancia.toDouble(), Distance.UNIT_KILOMETERS))
    val durationSpan = DurationSpan.create(duracion.toLong())

    val routeItem = Row.Builder()
        .setTitle(CarText.create("From current to A"))
        .addText(CarText.create("Distance: $distanceSpan"))
        .addText(CarText.create("Duration: $durationSpan"))
        .setMetadata(
            Metadata.Builder()
                .setPlace(placeA)
                .build()
        )
        .build()
    val itemList = ItemList.Builder()
        .addItem(routeItem)
        .build()

    builder.setItemList(itemList)

    val navigateAction = Action.Builder()
        .setTitle("Iniciar Navegación")
        .setOnClickListener {
         //TODO IMPLEMENT NAVIGATION
        }
        .build()

    builder.setNavigateAction(navigateAction)

    return builder.build()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Step 10 of the Learn Car App Library Fundamentals codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/car-app-library-fundamentals#9) shows an example of how to do this!

The issue with what you're doing right now is that `"Distance: $distanceSpan"` doesn't actually apply the span, it just uses [Kotlin string interpolation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-idioms-strings.html#concatenate-strings), resulting in a regular string, not a spanned string.

[Spantastic text styling with Spans](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568)  has more details on working with spans in general, which also applies to the [car specific spans](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/model/CarSpan) like the `DistanceSpan`, `DurationSpan` mentioned here, and others like the `CarIconSpan`